# Python and docker-compose - container stops

Tags: python, docker-compose

I'm trying to build a hello world app in python with `docker-compose` and web container won't stay running, it stops on build.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine

ADD . /code
WORKDIR /code

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD [ "python", "./app.py" ]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
    web:
        build: .
        ports:
            - "5000:5000"
        volumes:
            - ".:/code"
```

**app.py**

```py
x = 1
if x == 1:
    # indented four spaces
    print("x is 1.")
```

Comment: docker will exit when main process finishes. In your case, app.py is a simple script which ends immediately. If you are intended to make a web app, you need to make app.py to not terminating the main process. You can use any python web framework to do so for easiness.

Comment: A minimal example to test this would be to change your CMD to `[ "python", "-m", "http.server", "5000" ]`.